# Video Encoded using FFmpeg is not being played in Azure Kinect Viewer

Tags: ffmpeg, video, codec, kinect

I captured a video using a Kinect Azure DK device and could play it back using Azure Kinect Viewer (v.1.4.1). However, when I encode a video using FFmpeg, the commands are given below. I can not playback the video using Azure Kinect Viewer. I get a message:

> Failed to open Recording

```
ffmpeg -i .\RGB.mkv -c:v libx264 -preset veryfast -crf 18 -c:a aac -b:a 128k RGG_Enc.mkv

ffmpeg -i .\RGB.mkv -c:v mjpeg -pix_fmt yuvj422p -q:v 2 output.mkv
```

I tried with different codecs and different settings, but could not play the video in Azure Kinect Viewer. Can someone suggest to me what to do?

This [video](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1pmZmExeBkSsPr4hnO2SgCmWjyx3uNToe/view?usp=drive_link) contains only one channel (RGB) from the original video. I am able to play this video using Azure Kinect Viewer.

Here is the output of the `FFprobe`

```
  C:\Users\Ashutosh\Desktop\RGB_Encoding> ffprobe -i .\RGB.mkv
  ffprobe version 6.0-full_build-www.gyan.dev Copyright (c) 2007- 
 2023 the FFmpeg developers
 built with gcc 12.2.0 (Rev10, Built by MSYS2 project)
 configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-static -- 
 disable-w32threads --disable-autodetect --enable-fontconfig -- 
 enable-iconv --enable-gnutls --enable-libxml2 --enable-gmp -- 
 enable-bzlib --enable-lzma --enable-libsnappy --enable-zlib -- 
 enable-librist --enable-libsrt --enable-libssh --enable-libzmq -- 
 enable-avisynth --enable-libbluray --enable-libcaca --enable-sdl2 
 --enable-libaribb24 --enable-libdav1d --enable-libdavs2 --enable- 
 libuavs3d --enable-libzvbi --enable-librav1e --enable-libsvtav1 -- 
 enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxavs2 
 --enable-libxvid --enable-libaom --enable-libjxl --enable- 
 libopenjpeg --enable-libvpx --enable-mediafoundation --enable- 
 libass --enable-frei0r --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi -- 
 enable-liblensfun --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvmaf --enable- 
 libzimg --enable-amf --enable-cuda-llvm --enable-cuvid --enable- 
 ffnvcodec --enable-nvdec --enable-nvenc --enable-d3d11va --enable- 
 dxva2 --enable-libvpl --enable-libshaderc --enable-vulkan -- 
 enable-libplacebo --enable-opencl --enable-libcdio --enable-libgme 
 --enable-libmodplug --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopencore-amrwb 
 --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libshine --enable-libtheora --enable- 
 libtwolame --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libilbc --enable- 
 libgsm --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopus --enable- 
 libspeex --enable-libvorbis --enable-ladspa --enable-libbs2b -- 
 enable-libflite --enable-libmysofa --enable-librubberband -- 
 enable-libsoxr --enable-chromaprint

 libavutil      58.  2.100 / 58.  2.100
 libavcodec     60.  3.100 / 60.  3.100
 libavformat    60.  3.100 / 60.  3.100
 libavdevice    60.  1.100 / 60.  1.100
 libavfilter     9.  3.100 /  9.  3.100
 libswscale      7.  1.100 /  7.  1.100
 libswresample   4. 10.100 /  4. 10.100
 libpostproc    57.  1.100 / 57.  1.100

 [matroska,webm @ 0000018ef5f4e240] Could not find codec parameters 
 for stream 1 (Attachment: none): unknown codec
 Consider increasing the value for the 'analyzeduration' (0) and 
 'probesize' (5000000) options

 Input #0, matroska,webm, from '.\RGB.mkv':
 Metadata:
 title           : Azure Kinect
 encoder         : libebml v1.4.4 + libmatroska v1.7.1
 creation_time   : 2023-08-04T11:52:43.000000Z
 Duration: 00:00:40.03, start: 0.033000, bitrate: 126708 kb/s
 Stream #0:0(eng): Video: mjpeg (Baseline) (MJPG / 0x47504A4D), 
 yuvj422p(pc, bt470bg/unknown/unknown), 2048x1536, SAR 1:1 DAR 4:3, 
 30 fps, 30 tbr, 1k tbn (default)
 
 Metadata:
 title           : COLOR
  BPS             : 126696930
  DURATION        : 00:00:40.029000000
  NUMBER_OF_FRAMES: 1201
  NUMBER_OF_BYTES : 633943931
  _STATISTICS_WRITING_APP: mkvmerge v76.0 ('Celebration') 64-bit
  _STATISTICS_WRITING_DATE_UTC: 2023-08-04 11:52:43
  _STATISTICS_TAGS: BPS DURATION NUMBER_OF_FRAMES NUMBER_OF_BYTES

Stream #0:1: Attachment: none
Metadata:
  filename        : calibration.json
  mimetype        : application/octet-stream
 Unsupported codec with id 0 for input stream 1
```

Comment: Add `-pix_fmt yuv420p` and check.

Comment: It does not work. I receive this message "failed to open recording"

Comment: Might have something to do with profile. Can you add the ffprobe output of the video that works anyway?

Comment: Maybe all it supports is less-efficient codec like MJPEG.

Comment: I have also used this command `ffmpeg -i .\RGB.mkv -c:v mjpeg -pix_fmt yuvj422p -q:v 2 output.mkv`

Comment: Maybe also see if it has something to do with the muxing. See if the output of `ffmpeg -i in.mkv -c:v copy out.mkv` works first. (Or even better, extract the MJPEG stream with something like `ffmpeg -i in.mkv -c:v copy -f mjpeg imm.meh` and then remux it with `ffmpeg -i imm.meh -c:v copy out.mkv`.)

Comment: The first command did not work. With the other two commands, I do not see the error `failed to open the recording`. However, the screen in completely blank.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/148885/discussion-between-ashutosh-singla-and-tom-yan).

Comment: I see the the command you are trying is the result of a MSFT response on their forms. What is the desired outcome. As I understand it you have a video made by the device, and the viewer made for that output does play the video. What are you trying to to do the video specifically and for what purpose to alter it from the one that works. What is the *need* to encode thorough ffpmeg? With an understanding of the need, the suggestions/help may be easier.

Comment: I would like to play an `encoded` version of the RGB.mkv in `Azure Kinect Viewer`. The encoded video does not work. If I analyze the `metadata` between the `original` and the `encoded` video, I see the difference in `Encoder`. `Ori_Vid_Encoder: libebml v1.4.4 + libmatroska v1.7.1` and `Enc_Vid_Encoder: Lavf60.3.100`.